# How should I document travel by vehicle in the Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm planning to apply for a Schengen visa from the UK, where I reside on a 3-year business visa/resident permit. I'm self employed.

The Schengen application asks for evidence of travel such as flight tickets. However, I will go there with my British friend in his vehicle. How should I show that in the application? What sort of proof is needed when travelling by private vehicle?

Comment: How are you getting the car across the channel?

Comment: Where do you see that you must buy flight tickets to apply for the visa? That is incorrect, so you should consider whether your source is trustworthy and whether you have interpreted the information correctly.

Comment: You've got a Eurotunnel or a ferry booking, no?

Answer (score 4):

The Schengen visa form asks how you plan to pay for the trip. Prepaid travel and accomodations are *one* possible way to document this. Here is a Schengen visa [form](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/cae/servlet/contentblob/350388/publicationFile/212771/VisumantragEngl.pdf), with "other (please specify)" as an option.